# 2024 - Voice / Speech Recognition software - both with and without AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, software

it looks like all the questions about this topic are at least a few years old, and technology advances quickly, so I'll go ahead and ask. At this time (Feb 2024), what are the top and/or the best voice and speech recognition software options?

I am thinking of something that will recognize words and sentences. I am in the dreaming/thinking stage of a project. In one part of the project, the software would ask the user to repeat a couple of words, a sentence or two, or even maybe a paragraph or two. I would want the software to be able to be fairly certain (within an acceptable margin of error) as to whether the respondent said the phrases they were supposed to say.

I am interested in both free and paid options, subscription or one-time payment, open-source or closed source, AI-backed or non-AI backed. I am looking for as many options as possible. Again, I am just in the thinking stage, so there is no imagined budget. I am just trying to get info to see if my project is feasible.

This is only one part of the project. I am reluctant to share the details of the project itself, in case I want to pursue it. If I decide not to pursue it, I might share the details at that point for anyone who might want to pursue it.

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: Would you mind linking to the most similar (but old) question? See https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/have-things-changed-questions

Comment: yes, thank you. I upvoted it and checkmarked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Whisper](https://openai.com/research/whisper) is very popular AI-based one right now, with various implementations, such as open source [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) (Python) or [Whisper.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp).

It can use bunch of different models, which can be found e.g. [here](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/blob/master/models/README.md#available-models) for the C++ version. Of course the larger the models, the tougher/longer but more accurate the computations will be. Note that there are also various versions of the software, e.g. the default C++ one relies on processor, but you can potentially also use one that utilizes [CUDA](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp?tab=readme-ov-file#nvidia-gpu-support).